# how to avoid re-scale on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with two classes `box` and `shake`, both of them with attached animations. When mouse goes over the box I remove the `shake` class. When this happens I expect it to only stop shaking but it also plays the `box` animation from the beginning re-scaling the element. Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

Also I expected the `box` animation(scaling) to happen on document load. Why does it not happen? Can an element only have assigned one animation at a time? else does it overwrite?

```js
$("#boxDiv").on("mouseenter", function(){
  $("#boxDiv").removeClass('shake');
});

$("#boxDiv").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $("#boxDiv").addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
.box{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  background:green;
  animation: scaleOnLoad .5s ease 1s;
}

@keyframes scaleOnLoad {
  0%{    
    transform: scale(.2);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.shake {
  animation: shakeOnHover .1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes shakeOnHover {
  0% { transform: rotate(1deg); }
  33% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  66% {  transform: rotate(-1deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxDiv" class="box shake"></div>
```

Comment: You are trying to make two animations on the same element. They overwrite each other. When you remove the class the other animation has time to run.

Comment: Does the boxDiv start off with the two classes or just one (and if so, which one?)

Comment: @AHaworth starts with both

Comment: Is there a way with javascript/jquery to add a class that has an animation but have it load directly at the end of the animation, or skipping the animation part on addition of the class?

Comment: Since your are using JavaScript add your second class after load and remove the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description it sounds as though the boxDiv has both class box and class shake set.

As .shake comes after .box in the CSS any values set in .shake will overwrite any set in .box. You would expect this to happen if it were say setting background-color to red. So it is with the animation - the shake one overwrites the box one.

Hence, on loading the box shakes but doesnt scale. Try having boxDiv with just the box class to start with.

Then when you add and remove the box and shake classes the div will have only one.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your animations with animationend event like this:

```js
$(".box.loading").on("animationend", function(event){
  let box = $(event.target);
  box.removeClass('loading');
  box.addClass('shake');
});

$(".box").on("mouseenter", function(event){
  let box = $(event.target);
  if (!box.hasClass("loading")) {
    box.removeClass('shake');
  }
});

$(".box").on("mouseleave", function(){
  let box = $(event.target);
  if (!box.hasClass("loading")) {
    $(".box").addClass('shake');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  background:green;
}

.loading {
  animation: scaleOnLoad .5s ease;
}

@keyframes scaleOnLoad {
  0%{    
    transform: scale(.2);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.shake {
  animation: shakeOnHover .1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes shakeOnHover {
  0% { transform: rotate(1deg); }
  33% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  66% {  transform: rotate(-1deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box loading"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I did not know about the `animationend ` event